# How to make faster DB updates with Spring JPA and Hibernate for a hierarchy of entities in one-to-many relationships

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

## TLDR

Hi, we seem to have hit a ceiling of the throughput we can squeeze out of our database layer. And we believe that our load, although not small, is not something that impressive.
We observe that, although we believe we have free capacity of connections, both in the app's and the DB's connection pools, we can't execute many concurrent transactions effectively. **The more threads we add, above a certain threshold, the slower becomes each transaction, resulting in relatively constant processing throughput** regardless of the count of threads we throw at it. For now we have set it to 10 threads as it appears that this gives us the optimal throughput. Apart from the multithreding constraint, we believe we should be able to make the Db updates faster as a whole.

## In details:

We have a Spring boot application, using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, running in a docker container. The underlying DB is MariaDb.

The bulk of our model consists of entity `First`, that has a `one-to-many` relationship with entity `Second`, that has a `one-to-many` relationship with entity `Third`. There are no many-to-many relationships.

The flow is basically the following:
As data flows in, we open a transaction, using Spring's @Transactional, fetch an entity First, update some of First's and its childrens properties, and in some occasions add new child entities. Then we call firstRepository.save and the transaction is committed. Save is called because First itself, or any of its children, may be a newly created entity.
This is done concurrently using several threads where each thread works on a separate First instance.
The business logic involved takes a minuscule amount of time. The majority of the time spent is for reading, saving and transaction commit. The last includes everything String's @Transactional proxy does in relation to committing the transaction.

For now, we are not able to avoid the routine of reading entire First, because after any update in First, or its children, we need to send the entire object over to the next system - always sending the entire snapshot.

We have several indexes on each of the entities - First, Second, Third
Their relationship is enforced with foreign keys.

In our efforts to increase the throughput we tried a lot of advice in terms of working with Hibernate and MariaDb, like:

- Level 2 caching from Hibernate, which in our case is implemented by EhCache
- Hikari datasource with large connection pool == 30, which is never completely used up
- MariaDb has even larger pool == 10000
- batching inserts and updates by Hibernate
- eager fetching of child entities to reduce DB round trips. Remember we need all children anyway, even those that are not updated, because we have to pass on the entire `First` latest snapshot, so lazy loading does not save us anything
- our DB engine is `InnoDb`, which is supposed to only lock certain records and not entire tables

All these listed above do help, but we still appear to be slow - a large update in First and its children may take up to 2-3 seconds. the constraint in our multithreading doesn't seem to be affected by these optimizations.

We don't understand why we can't squeeze more of our DB layer. Currently we have approximately `600k` records for `First`, `28M` of `Second` and `100M` of `Third`.
This makes an average of 50 Second for each First and 4 Third for each Second. However we are usually not actively using more than a set of 5000 First at a time. In other words, most of the data is not in active use most of the time.

I have a suspicion that it may be miss-configuration in Hikari or the BD itself, that limits the connections that are actually used, or that makes the DB locks more rows than is necessary.
But I have no idea how to diagnose these.

## Some source code snippets:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "first", indexes = { 
        @Index(name = "blah1_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah1Id"),
        @Index(name = "blah2_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah1Id"),
        @Index(name = "blah3_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah2Id"),
        @Index(name = "blah4_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah3Id") })
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class First {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @OrderBy("typeId asc")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Second> second = new HashSet<Second>();

    /**
    There are 24 more columns, some of which are @Lob
    **/

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "second", indexes = { 
        @Index(name = "blah100_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah100"),
        @Index(name = "blah101_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah101"),
        @Index(name = "blah102_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah102"),
        @Index(name = "blah103_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah103") })
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Second {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private First parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @OrderBy("line asc, caption  desc")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private List<Third> third = new ArrayList<Third>();


    /**
    There are 11 more columns, none of which are @Lob
    **/
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "third", indexes = { 
        @Index(name = "blah200_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah200"),
        @Index(name = "blah201_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah201"),
        @Index(name = "blah202_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah202"),
        @Index(name = "blah203_inx", unique = false, columnList = "blah203") })
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Third {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Second parent;


    /**
    There are 16 more columns, none of which are @Lob
    **/
}
```

We use a vanilla JpaRepository for fetching and saving

```
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long> {
    ...
}
```

Creating/updating the data:

```
@Transactional(
        propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,
        rollbackFor = {Exception.class}
    )
    public First process(Long id) {
    firstRepository.findById(id)
                .orElse(new First(id));
        
    // update somo of first's attributes, and some of attributes of first children
    // ...
    
    return firstRepository.save(first);
     
    }
```

## Configuration

- the tables in the DB all use InnoDb engine and row format = Dynamic.
- Some of the text fields in First are large - Type = longtext
- Transaction isolation is the default, which should be REPEATABLE READ
- We don't do explicit locking in Hibernate

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://${DB_HOST}:3306/${DB_DATABASE}?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=27000
#Hibernate l2 cache properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

Some DB settings that may be of interest:

```
MariaDB  Ver 15.1
max_connections = 10000 (no idea why they set that much here)
expire_logs_days = 3
InnoDB settings:
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32G
```

Comment: " a large update in First and its children may take up to 2-3 seconds" - this seems to be the place to start; show some of the actual queries hitting the database and where is the time going?  If you are not already, inserting/updating multiple Second/Third records in a single request is going to be much faster

Comment: another way to say it: as phrased, your question isn't really answerable without someone knowing well all of your exact set of products; if you think the underlying problem is the database itself, focus on that.  show the table schemas and the sets of read and write queries and their explain plans and how long they are taking and ask for help with just the database layer.

Comment: If you are calling that transactional method in a loop it will be slow. As each will have a single transaction. Transactions are slow, having only a single tx will also render batching of statements useless as there is always just 1. What you should do is remove the transactional, execute everything in 1 large transaction. Do a flush/clear every x records (your batch size). But that is all based on assumptions as there is too little code/information here to help you.